# Python pyproj convert ecef to lla

Tags: python, coordinate-transformation

I want to convert x/y/z-ECEF positions to lla (lat/lon/alt) using WGS84 in python with pyproj but it seems like the conversion fails.

Example code is here:

```
import pyproj

# Example position data, should be somewhere in Germany
x = 652954.1006
y = 4774619.7919
z = -2217647.7937

ecef = pyproj.Proj(proj='geocent', ellps='WGS84', datum='WGS84')
lla = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong', ellps='WGS84', datum='WGS84')
lon, lat, alt = pyproj.transform(ecef, lla, x, y, z, radians=True)

print lat, lon, alt
```

Can someone see where the problem is?

EDIT: By now I guess the calculations are correct, just the data I get from my receiver seems to be faulty. Can someone confirm that?

Comment: Confirmed. pyproj is calculating correctly. Simple edge cases to verify: a) Center of the Earth: (x, y, z) =(0,0,0), then (lon, lat, alt) = (0, 90, -6356752.3).  b) Greenwich: (x,y,z) = (6378137,0,0), then (lon, lat, alt) = (0,0,0). Notice the oblateness of the Earth is taken into account by pyproj.

Comment: Also note that pyproj.transform() returns (lon, lat, alt) instead of (lat,lon,alt) and inputs and outputs are in meters instead of the more commonly used km.

Answer (score 12):

Latest pyproj version style

```
import pyproj

transformer = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(
    {"proj":'geocent', "ellps":'WGS84', "datum":'WGS84'},
    {"proj":'latlong', "ellps":'WGS84', "datum":'WGS84'},
    )
x = 652954.1006
y = 4774619.7919
z = -2217647.7937
lon1, lat1, alt1 = transformer.transform(x,y,z,radians=False)
print (lat1, lon1, alt1 )
```

You got
-24.887220848803032 82.2128095673836 -1069542.1692923503

Answer (score 10):

I tested it with my own self-made coordinate transformation program and have to say the correct order is:

```
lon, lat, alt = pyproj.transform(ecef, lla, x, y, z, radians=True)
```

I think when the designed the library they prefered to think about the longitude as the x-axis and latitude as the y-axis, so they returned it in that order.

I prefer to use degree, so it is easier for me to read it:

```
lon, lat, alt = pyproj.transform(ecef, lla, x, y, z, radians=False)
print lat, lon, alt
```

There the ouput is:

```
-24.8872207779 82.2128095674 -1069542.17232
```

I changed the z value to get a more reasonable value which is placed 'near' the surface:

```
x= 652954.1006
y = 4774619.7919
z =-4167647.7937
```

Then I get:

```
-41.0445318235 82.2128095674 2274.39966936
```

You can also see that only the latitude value is changing and the longitude is independent of the z-value. This is due to the fact that the z-axis is pointing to the north-pole.

If you want to read more about how this transformation is done look at this short description:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#From_geodetic_to_ECEF_coordinates

Comment: I recommend to use `t=pyproj.Transformer.from_proj(ecel, lla)` `t.transform(x, y, z, radians=False)` if you need to transform a lot of points. It is significantly faster in version 2.1.0. Also see [the documentation](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/advanced_examples.html#advanced-examples)

Answer (score -3):

```
lon, lat, alt = pyproj.transform(ecef, lla, x, y, z, radians=True)
```

Should be :

```
lat, lon, alt = pyproj.transform(ecef, lla, x, y, z, radians=True)
```

Since `lla = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong', ellps='WGS84', datum='WGS84')` specify the `latlong` order

Comment: @ Peramanathan . How to load input three columns  from a csv file and store the output file also in csv file after conversion.

Comment: pyproj returns (lon, lat, alt).  I agree (lat, lon, alt) would be more intuitive but that's not what it returns.