# transforming coordinates in python from geographic to Cartesian returns infinities

Tags: python, gis

I am using pyproj to project geographic coordinates onto the cartesian plane and it returns infinites and I don't know why. I based it on this [example stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30307311/python-pyproj-convert-ecef-to-lla) where I just did the opposite of what they do in this post.

Why does it return infinite?

```
In : import pyproj
In : lla = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong', ellps='WGS84', datum='WGS84')
In : ecef = pyproj.Proj(proj='geocent', ellps='WGS84', datum='WGS84')
In : pyproj.transform(lla, ecef, -32.1, -132.2, 5, radians=True)
Out: (inf, inf, 5.0)
```

Comment: if i remove the datum in both lla and ecef everything works. However I don't know why that changes it. The removing the datum idea came from [the documentation](https://jswhit.github.io/pyproj/pyproj-module.html#transform).